# SVG with viewport doesn't scale in Chrome

Tags: svg

I noticed that some of my SVGs (such as [this one](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/90ff389775567f1396c187a91ebdcac78f633335/68747470733a2f2f6e7363686c6f652e6769746875622e696f2f6d657368696f2f6d657368696f5f6c6f676f2e737667))

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0.000 0.000 10.000 10.000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>polygon {fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.04;}</style>
  <polygon points="7.499,8.421 7.462,8.845 7.042,8.603"/>
  <polygon points="1.433,3.243 1.562,2.775 1.130,2.929"/>
  <!-- [...] -->
</svg>
```

don't change sizes when treated with the magnifying glass in Google Chrome; you cannot make them larger or smaller. It does work in Firefox.

Is this a Chrome bug or a consequence of the SVG specification?

Comment: If you load them as standalone files, their width is always interpreted as default 100%. Set explicit width and height attributes, and the browser should be able to scale them with the magnification tool (if that is what you meant).

Comment: Scales just fine here (Chrome 68)